# ¿Cómo puedo reportar preguntas que están duplicadas?

Tags: soporte, reportes

Solo me sale para reportar mis preguntas, pero he visto un par de preguntas duplicadas y quiero reportarlas pero no me aparece **reportar** en esas preguntas.

Gracias

Comment: El reporte de publicaciones es un privilegio que se otorga a los 15 puntos, como se menciona [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Answer (score 1):

Parece que hace 17 minutos lograste la reputación mínima requerida, la cual es 15 puntos. Vuelve a intentar.

Referencia

- [Reportar publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Comment: Sii, lo he logrado, es que pensaba que anteriormente ya podía. Gracias y disculpe las molestias.